# Accessing my model in Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am a newbie in Android.

I have an UI which access some content based on some model.
Currently I want to have a dummmy content.

Later on I can move to SQL lite or access any web service to fetch the content.
I have read about content providers.

What I understand now is

```
UI-> Content Provider -> Dummy Content based on model
```

Later on it can be

```
UI-> Content Provider -> Model ->DB
```

or

```
UI-> Content Provider -> Model ->WS call.
```

I want my UI developers just to use one class and I later on should be able to change my data source. Is using the content provider like I mentioned above is correct?

Comment: what do you mean by just one class? How does that matter?

Comment: What i mean is my UI should only access that particular class to fetch contents. As far as i know if i use content provider i don't need to explicitly have typed elements in my UI.